# Merge tables records

Tags: c#, merge, sql-server-2012, db2

Environment: Visual Studio 2010 (C#)

Problem description: 
I have a table: `tblA` (source: SQL Server 2012) 
Columns: `DrawingNo, PartNo, Test1, Test2, …`       total: 21 columns

I have another table:   `tblB`  (source: DB2)
Columns: `DrawingNo, PartNo, Company, Status`  total: 4 columns

Goal 1:

```
Loop through tblA records
        Loop through tblB records
            If tblA.DrawingNo = tblB.DrawingNo AND tblA.PartNo = tblB.PartNo then
                //skip this record
            Else
//insert into tblA a record with new DrawingNo (taken from tblB.DrawingNo) and PartNo (taken from tblB.PartNo) and blanked remaining fields
            End If
```

Finally, I have a table:    `tblC`  (source: SQL Server 2012) 
Columns: `DrawingNo, cTest1, cTest2, …`             total: 20 columns

Goal 2:

```
Loop through tblC records
        Loop through tblA records (this table already update with tblB records)
            If tblC.DrawingNo = tblA.DrawingNo then
                //Insert into tblA columns from tblC.cTest1, cTest2, …
            Else
                //Do nothing
            End If
```

Questions:

1. It seems to me the logic I try to implement not the best way to
   reach my goals.  Is it any other way to make it more efficient?
2. What is the best way to add records from `tblB` to `tblA` (see above problem description)?
3. What environment would be more efficient to use – SQL Server, C#, or combination?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it any other way to make it more efficient?

YES, create a `Linked Server` using `sp_addlinkedserver` stored procedure for the DB2 instance and then perform a normal `LEFT JOIN` query (or) `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to skip out the existing rows and then do `INSERT` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

select '' as columnName, , , from db2.
and you can get same columns from db2.
and then use "merge()" method as below
dsSql.merge(dsDB2). but before do like that 
please make sure, columns type must be same between dsSql and dsDB2.
How to sync column type is your quest~ :D

It looks like so easier than before.

Your code is good, I just add your result.
take a look at DataTble.BeginloadData()
I found it from stackoverflow afew days ago. it will bring more speed up your application, unfortunately I forgot its URL.

Combinations for what?
You mean,
Java + Tomcat + Oracle
C# + IIS + (Oracle or Sql Server)
and etc???